# Find diff between web pages

Tags: c#, .net, text, diff

With C# .NET i would like to DL 2 webpages and find the DIFF between the webpage. Then i would like to program my app to allow me to label specific dif areas then parse for a series of urls.

What diff lib may help me find each area?

Comment: What sort of "diff" are you looking for?  The HTML text itself?  The visual representations (including all the included css, images, etc.)?  The semantic meanings between the HTML texts of each page?

Comment: @John: Either, i dont -need- the html but i will be parsing links. As long as it can find where the date is, where the links i want are (say a username, subject, body or a set of links of unknown length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine that you'd need something that 'understood' HTML to be able to sensibly diff the two files. I haven't seen any such library, there are a few tools out there like DiffDog and HTML Match but no libraries.

I'm afraid you'd be starting from scratch on that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the web pages are xhtml strict you could possibly use the MS [XML diff tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)

It should give you a starting point to work from at least!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of utilities that should do this.

If you want a very simple way to approach it, create a utility that will split the HTML files into words at whitespace and  and then compare. I've done this and it's worked well; and it's not hard to do.  HTH...